# What word would you use to describe someone who tries to one up everything you say?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

What word is appropriate for someone who tries to one up everything you say?  For example:

> Me: "You are a great friend"
>   Person: "Well, you are my best friend"

Comment: "that guy"...don't be that guy ;)

Comment: last word freak :-)

Comment: [Münchausen syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchausen_syndrome).

Comment: I've heard such a person described as a 'black cat' - because if you had a black cat, he'd have one that was blacker!

Answer (score 6):

As implied by the question itself, the standard term for the behaviour itself is [one-upmanship](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/one-upmanship).

Although *alphadictionary.com* is prepared to accept [one-upman](http://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/one-upmanship) as a word in itself, to be honest I think they're in the minority on that one. In the absence of a convenient single-word derivation from the standard term, people usually just say it using more words - for example...

> He always has to [one-up everything](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22one-up%20everything%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) you say. *(lots of written instances in that link)*

Most of us indulge in one-upmanship from time to time - it's part of normal social interaction. It only becomes tiresome with those few people who do it excessively. The most common single-word adjective I can think of for such a person is *competitive*. Which has lots of other shades of meaning, but when used in the context of how someone interacts socially, I think most people will know exactly what you mean.

[user653's](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/653/user653) comment to @Barrie's answer reminds me of my favourite example from Dilbert...

[image]

Comment: There's another word, which I can't for the moment remember. Perhaps someone else will come up with it.

Comment: @Barrie: the one I'm thinking about is much better.

Comment: There's a great phrase in colloquial usage around the Humber; "If you've got a dog then he's got a blacker 'un!". "'Un" is often replaced with an epithet implying illegitimacy...

Comment: The *OP* is describing something more like a flatterer. One-upmanship is more about various seemingly trifling ploys and tricks, (without actual cheating), to win some game or game-like scenario. At its worst, one-upmanship is misapplied to scenarios better left ungamed.

Answer (score 5):

I've remembered the word I was trying to think of earlier. It's *topper*, although it's not in the OED as such.

Comment: The Dilbert cartoon occasionally features a character by that name exhibiting this trait. "That's nothing!" he will say, before out-doing the main character, often implausibly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exact by any stretch, but *show-off* could work.

Comment: It's not showing off. It's just constantly attempting to out-do others.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of @Barrie, in our family someone exhibiting this trait would be called a *story-topper*. Whether this is a commonly used term I have no idea, but it should be!

Answer (score -1):

“academic” (as a noun) could be used, given that one-upmanship is endemic to academia.

Me: “You are a great friend.”

Person: “Well, you’re my best friend.”

Me: “Oh, don’t be an academic.”

(or: Me: “Oh, don’t play the academic.”)