# A single word that means or describes a person who has to have the last word in a discussion

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I am looking for a single word that is either a noun (like 'liar') or an adjective (like 'talkative') for a person who always has to have the last word in a discussion.

Comment: The best I can offer is that he has "ocd," which means an anxiety disorder in which people have unwanted and repeated thoughts, feelings, ideas, sensations (obsessions), or behaviors that make them feel driven to do something (compulsions). The key is to focus on "feel driven to do something."

Comment: related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46627/what-word-would-you-use-to-describe-someone-who-tries-to-one-up-everything-you-s

Comment: "The guy who always has a comeback after I give the authoritative answer."

Comment: Members of 'the red team'; 'type-A'; *competitive*.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46627/what-word-would-you-use-to-describe-someone-who-tries-to-one-up-everything-you-s), [**one-upman**](http://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/one-upmanship) is regarded as an acceptable word.  A use case:

> Don't bother arguing with Phil, he will always try to **one-up** you.

However, this doesn't really embody "a person who always has to have the last word."  There are several other words that having the last word might be a symptom of, like **stubborn, know-it-all,** or  **egocentric,** but again, being a *last-worder* is but a symptom of these traits.

Perhaps, if this person always needed to get the last-word in under their breath, we could call them an **ultimumbler**, a combination of the Latin word *ultimum* and the English word *mumble*.
While I do like saying **ultimumbler**, it looks horrendous on my screen.

Answer (score 2):

An **outtalker**. Some definitions for **outtalk**:

> - To talk more, longer, or louder than (someone)
>
>   > http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outtalk
> - Outdo or overcome in talking
>
>   > http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/out-talk

Comment: Closest so far!